# Sharepoint2010 issue list adding todays time based on choice in other column?

Tags: 2010, list, list-item, timestamp

in sharepoint 2010 I  would like to add a column that is blank in all cases except when a specific option is chosen in another column . Then I would like to add the time it was saved.

so for example when a user adds a item or modified an existing field in an item this column will record the time that field was modified. I have tried using the modified column but this would change the time values in the other columns I have using modified  to the new updated date of modification in the same item not just in the modification of the specific field I wanted).

IS there a way to do this without having access to share point designer??

for example If I select a date in a field in item1  in column a then column c will timestamp the time I saved that. then next day I select a date in column b then column d will timestamp the time I saved that. So column c and column d will have different times and column c timestamp will not update to the same time as column d

I hope this makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done with a Workflow (so you need SharePoint Designer) which tracks which field was changed and then sets other (timestamp) fields.

It can not be done with Calculated Columns as they are re-calculated for every change

Working in a No-SharePoint Designer environment is like working in a kitchen without a knife.

Get out of that kitchen and find yourself a new job.